# Grafana Assign Selected Result to Variable

Tags: grafana-variable

I have a Grafana panel which displays a number of results as shown below:

[image]

If I select one of the results, say 11.EsAction.95.percentile, I would like the value EsAction assigned to a variable $Action. Once I have this, I can update results in a different panel.

Or, if you a more clever way of updating a different panel based on the selected action, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You'll need to manually select needed value of variable from variable drop down as usual.

Comment: I can do that but can you create that dropdown in the panel, and not at the top of the screen? It is a big dashboard and it isn't very efficient to scroll to the top every time you want to access the dropdown.

Comment: No.............

Comment: Thanks. That's disappointing. This would be such a great feature if it existed.